# Implementing the mutation rate in a genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Given an array such as

```
[1, 4, 6, 1, 10, 3, 24, 1]
```

And I wanted to implement a mutation rate of .2 let's say. Would I:

- always mutate 20% of my array entries, or
- mutate 0-20% of the entries?
- iterate over array and mutate each 20% of the time

I am unclear from literature how this is handled - or if there is even an agreed upon standard.

Note - I am a coder meddling with GA so bear with me in the lack of depth of GA knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: I've done a GA for the traveling salesman problem and I don't recall any standards for parameters. AFAIK, you can make it mean whatever you want.

Comment: That was my thought. I am looking at some code where they do the range but wasn't sure if it was standard. I guess trying to codify the concept of "a 20% probability".

Comment: That's right there is no standard way because the "best" way depends on the problem space. Try each way and see which works best for your problem.

Comment: Alright. thanks for input

Comment: Good [explanation](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_the_mutation_rate_in_genetic_algorithms_very_small) of mutation rate effects.

Answer (score 0):

I was unsure about that too when I started to learn about genetic algorithms. I decided it's best to give each gene a x% chance to be mutated (completely changed). In your case I would iterate over the array and whenever `Math.random()` is smaller than `0.2` I would set the current number to a new random one.

If you find that you don't get enough diversity you can also add one or two completely random individuals (I like to call them 'foreigners' since they don't have any common ancestors).